# deployJava.js - opening in a new window

Tags: javascript, java, applet

I am using `deployJava.js` from Oracle's deployment toolkit to deploy and run an applet. If java is not installed, the current page is redirected to the download Java Page. I do want to redirect the user to the download Java Page, however, I would like this to happen in a new window. Redirecting it in the same page means my session is lost which I don't want happening. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: FYI: Java for browsers is dieing fast, and already dead is some browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

Oracle provides a human-readable version of the js file here: https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt

EDIT: [

Change the `location.href` page navigation code within here:

```
IEInstall: function() {

    location.href = constructGetJavaURL(
       ...);
     return false;
},

done: function (name, result) {
},

FFInstall: function() {

    location.href = constructGetJavaURL(
       ...);
     return false;
},
```

to these:

`window.open(constructGetJavaURL(...));`

You might have to mess around with that code a bit, I can't try it out myself. ]

Comment: document.location = this.returnPage executes after Java is installed. this.returnPage has stored the URL of the page with the applet and the above line makes the browser return to that page after Java is installed. How will opening current page in new Window help?

Comment: You're completely correct, I wasn't saying that was the right code to replace, just giving you an idea of what to look for and how to change it. I've updated my answer with what I think is the right code to change. Note that I can't try this out myself.